# method reference Java using an inner class

Tags: java, methods, reference, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

```
public static class CompareClass {

    public static int  CompareBetweenStudents(Student student, Student othStudent) {
        return student.getNume().compareTo(othStudent.getNume());

    }

}

public List<Student> filterStudentsByLetter(String letter){

    Predicate<Student> predicate = x->x.getNume().indexOf(letter) == 0;
    Iterable<Student> list = getAllStudenti();
    Object[] objects = genericFilter(list, predicate, CompareClass::CompareBetweenStudents).toArray();
    return null;
}


public  <E> List<E> genericFilter(List<E> list, Predicate<E> predicate, Comparator<E> comp){
    return list.stream().filter(predicate).sorted(comp).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I am trying to make a comparable class to use in a filter but I keep getting CompareClass::CompareBetweenStudents as "Cannot resolve methodCompareBetweenStudents". How can I solve it?

Comment: I forgot to say that everyting is in a big class (I am trying to use inner class)

Comment: Edit your question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: Where is `CompareBetweenStudents` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement a class for that (comparing), you can simply do:

```
genericFilter(list, predicate, Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getName()))
```

There's one other issue though: you declare list as `Iterable<Student> list` but pass it as a `List<E> list`. That's not going to work, fix `getAllStudenti()` to return `List<Student>`

Comment: Only if using at least Java 8  though :)

Comment: @Lichtbringer true that. I pity those who don't, I'm on Java 9... :)

Answer (score 1):

The types of the parameters in `genericFilter(list, predicate, CompareClass::CompareBetweenStudents)` don't match the declared types of `genericFilter`.

The passed `list` is an `Iterable<Student>`,
but the `genericFilter` method expects `List<Student>`.

The passed `CompareClass::CompareBetweenStudents` is not a `Comparator<Student>`. To fix this parameter,
you can change the implementation of `CompareClass` this:

```
public static class CompareClass implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student student, Student othStudent) {
        return student.getNume().compareTo(othStudent.getNume());
    }
}
```

And then pass `new CompareClass()` to `genericFilter`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I found the mistake. Genericfilter get's a List but I pass as argument an iterable. After I changed from Iterable to List, it worked.

```
private <E> List<E> fromIterableToList(Iterable<E> iterableList){
    List<E> newList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(E e:iterableList){
        newList.add(e);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

And I called the function:

```
genericFilter(fromIterableToList(list), predicate, CompareClass::CompareBetweenStudents);
```

Comment: I explained this in my answer long before you posted this answer.